# upload ssh key on github from command line

Tags: git, json, github

I have found a way to upload an SSH key to my GitHub account with command line, but there is small problem.

I am able to do this with following command:

```
curl -u "user:pass" --data '{"title":"test-key","key":"ssh-rsa Aaa"}'
```

https://api.github.com/user/keys

But I am using this in Chef to add my nodes' keys to my GitHub account:

```
curl -u "user:pass" --data '{"title":"test-key","key":"`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`"}' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

but it is giving error.

What could be the reason?

Comment: You'll probably want to put the `cat` command in `$()` so that it gets ran rather than literally putting that string of text in as your SSH key.

Comment: On mobile so I can't type it all out but you'll probably have to change your quotes as well.

Comment: You could also used stdin instead of an option value. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77588/passing-binary-data-to-curl-without-using-a-file

Comment: i am using this is chef so i want a generic way to do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `cat` command results must be expanded using [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst).

The syntax for bash is:

```
curl -u "user:pass" --data '{"title":"test-key","key":"'"$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"'"}' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

You can also use a classic backtick notation:

```
curl -u "user:pass" --data '{"title":"test-key","key":"'`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`'"}' https://api.github.com/user/keys
```

Comment: i am using this in chef to update my node's ssh -key  in github. i am editing this in my question

Comment: you first option did the trick, thnks very much

Comment: To make this work with 2FA/TOTP add the header like so: `-H ‘x-github-otp: 123456‘` according to the docs here: https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#working-with-two-factor-authentication